# Can one allow lashon hara to be said about oneself?

Tags: sources-mekorot, lashon-hara-slander

Somewhat similar to the question of [saying lashon hara (negative speech) about oneself](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30372/lashon-hara-about-yourself): can a person forgo his right to privacy (if that has anything to with lashon hara) and allow other to speak negatively about him, either in particular circumstances or in general?

The end of [Sefer Chafetz Chaim Klal 2,](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47570&st=&pgnum=151) allows repeating something potentially harmful about someone if he himself has publicly revealed this information. This, to me, implies that if a person *specifically allowed* repeating harmful information than it should certainly be permitted to repeat. On the other hand, I got the feeling from other halachos in Sefer Chafetz Chaim (I can't bring any exact quotes, sorry) that it might be prohibited. Could this be a case where laws concerning harmful information be more strict than those regarding negative speech?

Is there anyone who provides a thorough discussion of this issue? It seems like it would come up very often.

Comment: I found an article on the topic from this year's המעיין, http://www.shaalvim.co.il/torah/maayan-article.asp?backto=30&ed=%E2%EC%E9%E5%EF%20%FA%F9%F8%E9%20%FA%F9%F2%E3&id=788 but I was hoping to find more sources

Comment: It would be helpful if you indicated where you had found Klal 2, so others could help determine it's applicability.

Answer (score 2):

Artscroll "Chofetz Chaim, A Lesson A Day" book, (page 68) states that derogatory speech may not be said even of someone who allows this to be said about himself, because "to speak negative of one's fellow is shameful in itself". The source for this (endnote 18) is given as Beer Mayim Chaim 2:28. The note further states (my translation from Hebrew):

> 'Rabbi Hillel Zaks [grandson of the Chofetz Chaim, who wrote an approbation to this book] wrote on this, "I heard from my father, who heard from his father-in-law the Chofetz Chaim ztz"l, who told him that he was unsure about this [law], and his opinion leaned towards leniency (without being decisive), but prevented himself from writing so in his book because he was afraid that it would come to mishap." However, this requires study [as in, the author of the footnote believes that there's a reason to say otherwise] because if the speaker doesn't cause harm to the subject there should be no reason to ask forgiveness from the subject anyways because it doesn't violate anything between man and his fellow, and if so, we aren't discussing [a right that is] given to be forgone.

Answer (score 1):

According to [R. Chaim Kanievsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Kanievsky) (Sefer Bakesh Shalom p. 32) it is permissible but not advisable, as it might lead one to become accustomed to speaking lashon hara.

> **שאלה ח.** האם מותר לספר לשה"ר על אדם שאינו מקפיד שמדברים עליו
>
> **תשובה.** מעיקר הדין מותר אבל ללא תועלת לא ידבר כמו שלא ידבר אפי' על
>   גוי כדי שלא יורגל לדבר לשה"ר

However, [R. Menashe Klein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menashe_Klein) has a responsum ([Shu"t Mishneh Halachos 17:171](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38243&st=&pgnum=319)) about this question and he disagrees, arguing that since a person is created in God's image, he does not have the right to forgo his honor.

> אחדשכ"ת בידידות בדבר שאלתו בדין לשה"ר מי שאינו מקפיד על שמדברים עליו
>   ואדרבה בפירוש אומר לבזותו בלשון הרע וכיוצא בו ויש צד לאסור אעפ"כ משום
>   דבצלם אלקים עשה את האדם ויש בו חלק של מעלה וא"כ הגם שמוחל על בזיונו
>   ואינו עובר על ואהבת לרעך כמוך מ"מ נשאר החלק אלוק ממעל וצלם אלקים שבו
>   מה שאין על חבירו הבעלות ע"ז למחול וכן דייק מרש"י סוף פ' יתרו שכתב ק"ו
>   ומה אבנים הללו שאין בהם דעת להקפיד על בזיונן אמרה תורה אל תנהג בהם
>   מנהג בזיון חבירך שהוא בדמות יוצרך ומקפיד על בזיונו על אחת כמה וכמה אלא
>   שראה פסק הלכה בשם הגר"ח קנייבסקי שליט"א בחוברת בקש שלום שאם אין אדם
>   מקפיד שיבזהו בלה"ר מותר מעיקר הדין רק כדי שלא יתרגל בלה"ר יש לו להימנע
>
> הנה יפה דייק מלשון רש"י ובתנחומא שם איתא וז"ל והרי דברים ק"ו ומה
>   אבנים שאין בהם דעת לא לטובה ולא לרעה הזהירך הקב"ה שלא לנהוג בהן מנהג
>   בזיון חבירך שהוא בדמותו של הקב"ה על אחת כמה וכמה וכן הוא במכילתא וז"ל
>   ומה אם אבנים שאין בהן דעת לא לרעה ולא לטובה אמר הקדוש ברוך הוא לא תנהג
>   בהן מנהג בזיון חברך שהוא בדמותו של מי שאמר והיה העולם דין הוא שלא
>   תנהוג בו מנהג בזיון ע"כ הרי שלא הזכירו רק זה הטעם שהוא בדמות ובצלם,
>   וע"ז אין ביד האדם למחול
>
> וקצת ראיה נמי ממעשה דר"א בר"ש (תענית כ') שהיתה דעתו גסה עליו מפני
>   שלמד תורה הרבה נזדמן לו אדם אחד שהיה מכוער ביותר, אמר לו שלום עליך רבי
>   ולא החזיר לו אמר לו ריקה כמה מכוער אותו האיש, שמא כל בני עירך מכוערין
>   כמותך אמר לו איני יודע אלא לך ואמור לאומן שעשאני כמה מכוער כלי זה
>   שעשית כיון שידע בעצמו שחטא ירד מן החמור ונשתטח לפניו ואמר לו נעניתי לך
>   מחול לי אמר לו איני מוחל לך עד שתלך לאומן שעשאני ואמור לו כמה מכוער
>   כלי זה שעשית ודו"ק ולשון הרמב"ם ז"ל במו"נ ח"ג פמ"ג שנפשו של אדם קנין
>   של הקב"ה ולא קנינו של אדם ועיין סמ"ה מצוה תי"ב ובחינוך שם
>
> וראה בדעת זקנים לבע"ת פ' בראשית עה"פ זה ספר תולדות אדם וז"ל ואהבת
>   לרעך כמוך אר"ע זה כלל גדול בתורה בן עזאי אומר זה ספר תולדות אדם גדול
>   יותר פי' אסיפיה דקרא קאי בדמות אלקים עשה אותו דמקרא דר"ע לא שמעינן אלא
>   דעלך סני לחברך לא תעביד ובא בן עזאי ואמר שאף אם הוא אינו חושש לכבוד
>   עצמו יש לו לחוש לכבוד חברו לפי שרואה דמות חברו ואינו רואה דמות עצמו
>   ולזה אמר שמקרא זה כולל יותר ממקרא דואהבת לרעך כמוך ע"ש
>
> ומ"ש בגמ' ב"ק דף צ"ג הכני פצעני ע"מ לפטור פטור שם לענין דיני ממונות
>   מיירי וכיון שמחל על בזיונו פטור בדיני אדם אבל לא שמותר לבזותו ואפילו
>   האדם בעצמו חייב לכבד את הדמות שעליו כי בצלם אלקים עשה את האדם ועיין
>   טור חו"מ סי' תכ"א