# Is one allowed to offer bounties on Mi Yodeya?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Mi Yodeya has a [bounty](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) feature, where a user gives away some of their reputation points to either attract or reward a high-quality answer (simplified).

However, we [learn](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/57879/5151) in the name of the Chafetz Chaim:

> You can't give up your reputation because it is not wholly yours to cede.

This would make it seem that using the bounty system is forbidden.

On the other hand, it could be that [reputation points are a Bad Thing in the first place](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9445/does-reputation-scoring-make-the-torah-a-crown-to-magnify-yourself-with), in which case it might be beneficial to get rid of some.

What do the sources say about this?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 4):

There are two gedarim in reputation, the Cheftza and the Gavra.

- Cheftza: Points as a currency
- Gavra: Points as an inherent sign of trust

For example, if [vram](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1172/baal-shemot-tovot) would give away all his rep, he would still be vram, and trusted by side users the same, while he would lose "power" to the recipient.

The Chofetz Chaim just said that the "Gavra level" isn't yours, it's owned by those who trust you (just as a name isn't really owned by the namee, and when he changes his name he needs to make *others* call him by his new name).

However, currency can (and should) be transferred (preferably to me)

Answer (score 2):

Reb Mordechai Shulsinger was opposed to bochurim entering Torah competitions to the extent that he once found one of his talmidim had won one, which made the talmid feel so bad he relinquished the prize.

On the other hand, someone once asked Reb Leib Gurwitz how come people say so many shvachim at seudas pereida's, surely we say only miktzas shvacho shel adam be'phanav?

He replied, If a cat told you you were a great guy would that give you a big head?

So the chakirah is, does Mi Yodea have the din of a Torah competition or a cat?

Answer (score 1):

He who chases honor, honor runs away from him. He who runs away from honor, honor pursues him. One is required to be an anav and recognize that the talents that enabled him to accumulate the reputation point comes from Hashem. Moshe Rabbeinu was called anav mikol adam. Thus, giving bounty points to someone who deserves it shows that you are being modest like Moshe Rabbeinu and deserving of even more reputation. Also just as Hashem reimburses you for the tzedakah and what you spend on Yom Tov, he will give you the seichel to answer more questions and garner more reputation.